# Saddle point, point of inflection, extremum, stationary point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, stationary-point

1. What is the difference between a point of inflection and a saddle point?
2. What is the difference between an extremum and a stationary point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A point of inflexion is a point where the tangent line exists and crosses the curve.  So the context is the graph of a 1-dimensional curve in 2 dimensions.  A saddle point is a point on a surface (so the context is a two dimensional surface in 3 dimensions.) where the tangent plane is horizontal, but the point is neither a max or a min.
2. A stationary point is a point where the derivative exists and is zero.  It may or may not be an extremum.  An extremum is either a local max or local min.  For instance the function $f(x) = |x|$ has a local min at $x=0$, but the derivative doesn't exist, and therefore it is not a stationary point.

Comment: "_A stationary point is a point where the derivative exists and is zero_" Stationary point can also be a point of inflection then?

Comment: @mithusengupta123  Yes.  $y=x^3$ at $x=0$ is an example.  The point is "stationary" because $y$ isn't changing at that point.  That is, $y'=0.$

Comment: Here is my summary of your answer. So a stationary point is maximum, minimum or a inflection point. A saddle point is a generalization of point of inflection for 2D surfaces. An extremum is a maximum of a minimum but does not count inflection points or saddle points. Please verify.

Comment: @mithusengupta123  I can't think of anything wrong with your summary.

Comment: @Solidification "*So a stationary point is maximum, minimum or a inflection point.*" $\quad$ The point $(0,3)$ of $f(x)=3$ is stationary but neither max, min, nor inflection.